# Blur anything that moves

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to blur humans filmed on police dash cameras. My strategy is to blur anything that moves. I found http://derek.simkowiak.net/motion-tracking-with-python/ but it uses an old version of OpenCV. I wasn't able to find any examples of blurring a region in the version of OpenCV used.

Code from the motion tracking example:

```
for box in trimmed_box_list:
    cv.Rectangle( display_image, box[0], box[1], cv.CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2 )
```

Code from example for newer version of OpenCV that blurs a region:

```
for (x, y, w, h) in results:

    detected = True
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    sub_face = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    # apply a gaussian blur on this new recangle image
    sub_face = cv2.GaussianBlur(sub_face,(23, 23), 30)
    # merge this blurry rectangle to our final image
    frame[y:y+sub_face.shape[0], x:x+sub_face.shape[1]] = sub_face
```

If anyone knows how to change the example for the older version of OpenCV that would be great or if you have better strategy for blurring anything that moves please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you've referenced is rather complicated for your specific idea; from what you've said, you don't need to worry about tracking any moving objects, only blur "anything that moves."

So to do that I would suggest simple background subtraction. [Here](http://feelmare.blogspot.com/2014/04/opencv-study-background-subtractor-mog.html) is a link that demonstrates three of the different methods that OpenCV supports.

And here is the code from that page:

```
#include < stdio.h>
#include < iostream>

#include < opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include < opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include < opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include < opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>


#ifdef _DEBUG        
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core247d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgproc247d.lib")   //MAT processing
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_objdetect247d.lib") //HOGDescriptor
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_gpu247d.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_features2d247d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_highgui247d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_ml247d.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_stitching247d.lib");
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_nonfree247d.lib");
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_video247d.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core247.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgproc247.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_objdetect247.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_gpu247.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_features2d247.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_highgui247.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_ml247.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_stitching247.lib");
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_nonfree247.lib");
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_video247d.lib")
#endif 

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



int main()
{

 //global variables
 Mat frame; //current frame
 Mat resizeF;
 Mat fgMaskMOG; //fg mask generated by MOG method
 Mat fgMaskMOG2; //fg mask fg mask generated by MOG2 method
 Mat fgMaskGMG; //fg mask fg mask generated by MOG2 method


 Ptr< BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG; //MOG Background subtractor
 Ptr< BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG2; //MOG2 Background subtractor
 Ptr< BackgroundSubtractorGMG> pGMG; //MOG2 Background subtractor



 pMOG = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG();
 pMOG2 = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
 pGMG = new BackgroundSubtractorGMG();


 char fileName[100] = "C:\\POSCO\\video\\/cctv 2.mov"; //Gate1_175_p1.avi"; //mm2.avi"; //";//_p1.avi";
 VideoCapture stream1(fileName);   //0 is the id of video device.0 if you have only one camera   

 Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3), Point(1,1) );   

 //unconditional loop   
 while (true) {   
  Mat cameraFrame;   
  if(!(stream1.read(frame))) //get one frame form video   
   break;

  resize(frame, resizeF, Size(frame.size().width/4, frame.size().height/4) );
  pMOG->operator()(resizeF, fgMaskMOG);
  pMOG2->operator()(resizeF, fgMaskMOG2);
  pGMG->operator()(resizeF, fgMaskGMG);
  //morphologyEx(fgMaskGMG, fgMaskGMG, CV_MOP_OPEN, element); 




  imshow("Origin", resizeF);
  imshow("MOG", fgMaskMOG);
  imshow("MOG2", fgMaskMOG2);
  imshow("GMG", fgMaskGMG);


  if (waitKey(30) >= 0)   
   break;   
 }

}
```

Using this as a base to find the moving objects in your scene, you can then blur them in a few ways. The lazy way that comes to mind for me would be to  **blur a copy of the image and then use the result of background subtraction as a mask to apply the blurred image to the original**. Done on each frame, this would blur anything that the background subtractor thinks is moving on a frame-by-frame basis. Blurring only rectangles around sufficiently large groupings of pixels from the background subtractor would probably be a good way to improve the efficiency once it is working. You could even pre-fill a Mat with any sort of noise you like and use that instead of the blurred copy.

It would get much more complicated if you were trying to only blur humans. A human detector is entirely doable but would get complicated if you wish to make sure that they are blurred on every frame (if we're talking about identity protection or something here), since the detector would likely miss some and you would *then* want to start guessing at where human was between frames. Anyway, you didn't ask for that, but FYI.